# Does upgrading Magento 1.x replace all core files?

Tags: magento-1.9, upgrade, magento-connect

I would just like to know if **ALL** core files are replaced with a Magento 1.x upgrade via Magento Connect? Or are there certain files that are ignored?

I never edit core files, but it's just something I'd be interested in understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes upgrade via Magento connect replaces all old files with new ones, also standard theme files. If this is not convenient, you can point-update the code, for this you should use patches that are also available on the download page

Answer (score 1):

When upgrading your Magento, you will lose any changes made anywhere in core files, which is just one reason why it's best to avoid touching them. Here's a nice guide that helps explain some alternative options and the reasons behind them:
https://www.demacmedia.com/magento-commerce/magento-upgrade-guide/